# jade if statement is not working

Tags: pug

I have the following non-functional code

```
div(class = "col-xs-8 inner")
    |   <label style="font-size:20px;"><%- meter_id %></label><br>
    if (type === "1")
    |   Electricity
    if (type === "0")
    |   Water
```

I am passing type as 1 and I still see both Electricity and Water in the output. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a level of indentation after the two `if`-statements:

```
div(class = "col-xs-8 inner")
    |   <label style="font-size:20px;"><%- meter_id %></label><br>
    if (type === "1")
        |   Electricity
    if (type === "0")
        |   Water
```

This is because Pug only associates indented code with such blocks. That is, after `if`-statements, it expects code belonging in its branch to be indented.

Comment: now it gives me nothing neither Electricity nor Water

Comment: Are you sure that `type` is well-defined (as either `"1"` or `"0"`)? I have tested this in an isolated environment, and it does work there if I give it one of those two values

Comment: I checked in my object model before rendering the template and model seems to have the correct type = "1" as string. the other variable meter_id is also there and that seems to be picking up by jade.

Comment: Here a [codepen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/oZNodJ), where it seems to work (with the right variable context). Could you maybe look into what it does differently compared to your codebase?

Comment: I am not passing 'type' as a variable in jade. instead I am passing a model into template like so:

Comment: this.template = _.template ($("#unit_details").html());
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

Comment: Ah ok, could you maybe try double- instead of triple-equality checking? (`==` instead of `===`). Could be something with the type of the variable. I'm finding it increasingly likely that this is something related to the way variables are passed into this template (after indentation is fixed)...

Comment: I am using underscore template inside jade template and therefore I required <% if (type === "1") { %>

Comment: Are you sure that the `type` variable is also passed to Pug (not only to underscore.js)? 

PS: Any particular reason for relying on two templating engines concurrently? Pug supports interpolation just fine (`#{}`), and judging from the snippet that you have provided here, your problem could just as well be solved with Pug alone...

Comment: I was using underscore as client template engine and pug as server template engine and client template needed to be defined inside server template.